# How to send ">' string in a java code to server

Tags: java

When i try to send a value "Login>Success" to server i get the value as Login%3ESuccess.
How can i send the greater than symbol in the java string.

Comment: You'll need to provide *much* more information about what you're doing. We have *no context at all* here. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you URLDecode the values on the server side?

Answer (score 2):

This question probably needs more context to be properly answerable, but I believe that you are looking at URL encoding at some point. You can use the methods on the [java.net.URLDecoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) class to do the decoding.

Answer (score 0):

Doc is here : http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html

And a code sample :

```
/**
 * @param yourText an urlencoded string.
 * @return utf8 decoded string.
 */
public String decodeString(String yourText) {
    return URLDecoder.decode( yourText, "UTF-8" ); // feel to change enconding
}
```